# Using react-bootstrap/Offcanvas in class component

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to use `Offcanvas` component from `react-bootstrap` within a class component. In my attempts I get the following error:

`Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

The [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/offcanvas/#placement) models the use of `Offcanvas` through a function component, so I'm not sure if there is a workable solution to use `Offcanvas` within my Class component or if I've just left out some important step.

Below are snippets of my code.

1. `App.js` is the parent component
2. `Cards.js` is a child component, rendering cards that have buttons - when clicked, they trigger the clickHandler() passed down from App.js
3. `MyCanvas.js` is the child component where my breakdown occurs

**App.js**

```
import { Component } from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Cards from "./Cards";
import MyCanvas from "./MyCanvas";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      report_id: 1,
      report_desc: "report name/id comes from Cards onClick",
      form_state: false,
    };
  }

  clickHandler(report_id, report_desc) {
    this.setState({
      form_state: true,
      report_id: report_id,
      report_desc: report_desc,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Cards clickHandler={this.clickHandler} />
        <MyCanvas
          show={this.state.form_state}
          key={this.state.report_id}
          placement={"bottom"}
          report_desc={this.state.report_desc}
        />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Cards.js**

```
import { Component } from "react";

class Cards extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [
        {
          report_id: 0,
          report_desc: "Example",
          report_desc_long: "Example description here",
          report_published_date: "01/01/2021",
          report_requests: 75,
          popular_flag: true,
        },
        {
          report_id: 1,
          report_desc: "Example2",
          report_desc_long: "Example description here",
          report_published_date: "01/01/2021",
          report_requests: 25,
          popular_flag: false,
        },
        {
          report_id: 2,
          report_desc: "Example3",
          report_desc_long: "Example description here",
          report_published_date: "01/01/2021",
          report_requests: 5,
          popular_flag: false,
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  cardItems() {
    const cardItems = this.state.items.map((i) => (
      <Card
        key={i.report_id}
        bg="light"
        border="dark"
        text={"light" ? "dark" : "white"}
        className="mb-2"
        style={{ width: "18rem" }}
        onClick={this.props.clickHandler}
      >
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>{i.report_desc}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>
            <div>
              Published {i.report_published_date}
            </div>
            <div>Count: {i.report_requests}</div>
          </Card.Text>
          <Card.Body>{i.report_desc_long}</Card.Body>
          <Button variant="outline-dark">Select</Button>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    ));
    return cardItems;
  }
  render() {
    return <div>{this.cardItems()}</div>;
  }
}

export default Cards;
```

**MyCanvas.js**

```
import { Component } from "react";
import Offcanvas from "react-bootstrap/Offcanvas";

class MyCanvas extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ show: true });
  }

  handleClose() {
    this.setState({ show: false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Offcanvas
          show={this.state.show}
          onHide={this.handleClose}
          {...this.props}
        >
          <Offcanvas.Header closeButton>
            <Offcanvas.Title>{this.props.report_desc}</Offcanvas.Title>
          </Offcanvas.Header>
          <Offcanvas.Body>
            Some text or other component goes here...
          </Offcanvas.Body>
        </Offcanvas>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyCanvas;
```